# adding incorrectly displaying

Tags: javascript

Fixed my code up. However, now the alert pops up saying your value is NaN. However, it is a number. The parseInt, helped a little bit. I am most likely missing something. Right now my code looks like this:

```
    <input id="a" type="text">


    <script>
        function myFunction()
            {
                x=document.getElementById("a").value;
                if(x==""||isNaN(x))
                    {
                        alert("Your First Number is Not Numeric");
                    }
                a=document.getElementById("a").value;   
            }
    </script>   

    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Submit Number</button>
    <br />
    <p>Second Number</p>
    <br />
    <input id="b" type="text">
    <script>
        function myFunction1()
            {
                x=document.getElementById("b").value;
                if(x==""||isNaN(x))
                    {
                        alert("Your Second Number is Not Numeric");
                    }
                b=document.getElementById("b").value;
            }
    </script>

    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction1()">Submit Number</button>
    <br />
    <script>
        function add()
            {
                d=parseInt(a);
                e=parseInt("b");
                c=d+e;
                alert("The number is " + c);
            }
    </script>
    <button type="button" onclick="add()">Add numbers</button>
```

Comment: Please note that Javascript is not the same as Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Input values *are* strings. Use `parseInt` or another means of converting them to a number fore you try to add them.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you do have strings instead of integers. You can use `parseInt` to convert them to integers before adding them.

Theres more info here:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp

Answer (score 1):

The value of an input is a string, not a number. You need to use `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()` to convert your string to a number before adding them.